# Refactoring blocking to async code using CompletableFuture

Tags: java, asynchronous, completable-future

### Situation

I did code refactoring using `CompletableFuture` for better performance.

A code is like below. (each result is independent.)

#### Code before refactoring

```java
public Map<String, Object> retrieve() {
  Object result1 = testProxy.findSomething(param1); // blocking
  Object result2 = testProxy.findSomething(param2); // blocking
  Object result3 = testProxy.findSomething(param3); // blocking

  Map<String, Object> toClient = new HashMap<>();
  toClient.put("result1", result1);
  toClient.put("result2", result2);
  toClient.put("result3", result3);
  
  return toClient;
}
```

#### Code after refactoring

```java
public Map<String, Object> retrieve() {
  CompletableFuture<Object> future1 =
                CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> testProxy.findSomething(param1));

  CompletableFuture<Object> future2 =
                CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> testProxy.findSomething(param2));

  CompletableFuture<Object> future3 =
                CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> testProxy.findSomething(param3));


  Map<String, Object> toClient = new HashMap<>();
  toClient.put("result1", future1.get());
  toClient.put("result2", future2.get());
  toClient.put("result3", future3.get());
  
  return toClient;
}
```

After refactoring, I got a better performance result. However, I found a code using while loop to check task is done before getting a result.

```java
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

CompletableFuture<String> future = new CompletableFuture<>(); // creating an incomplete future

executorService.submit(() -> {
   Thread.sleep(500);
   future.complete("value"); // completing the incomplete future
   return null;
});

while (!future.isDone()) { // checking the future for completion
   Thread.sleep(1000);
}

String result = future.get(); // reading value of the completed future
logger.info("result: {}", result);

executorService.shutdown();
```

---

### Questions

So, my questions are :

1. Did I code refactoring in right way using CompletableFuture ?
2. As far as I know, `get()` method blocks until task return result though, why the while loop needs ?
3. If I need to check whether all tasks are done, should I write code like this ?

```java
 CompletableFuture<Void> allFutures = CompletableFuture.allOf(future1, future2, future3);

 while(!allFutures.isDone()){}

 Map<String, Object> toClient = new HashMap<>();
  toClient.put("result1", future1.get());
  toClient.put("result2", future2.get());
  toClient.put("result3", future3.get());
```

Comment: You are still calling `get()` on the futute. That makes it blocking and you didnt gain much at all. Return the futures instead of the actual values. Then the user can decide whether to wait or continue an async chain using `thenSupplyAsync(...)` and similar.

Comment: Why do you create this map in the first place? Looks odd. You might as well just return a `List` of the results. Unless I am missing something cause its obviously an edited contrived setup.

Comment: Regarding your last question, get rid of the loop, that defeats the point of the futures. Just do `allFutures.join()`, then all are done.

Comment: In general, if you are using loops to wait on futures, you are likely doing it wrong. Either you wait until its done using `future.join()` or `future.get()`, or you continue an async chain using the `.thenXXX` methods. Dont do an actively blocking loop to wait, `join` does the same - better.

Comment: @Zabuzard Thanks to your comment, retrieve() method returns Map to client(React app) through RestController and client uses result1, 2 3 as a key to extract data from  response (json).

Comment: The first “Code after refactoring” is fine, the subsequent stuff is horrible. Why do you think you have to compare your code to something you “found somewhere”? Either, it’s a reputable source you can cite (which also usually explains why it does something in a certain way), or it’s not worth discussing.

Comment: @Holger Thank you for your advice! I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

### Is `CompletableFuture` used correct?

> 1. Did I code refactoring in right way using CompletableFuture ?

Your refactoring is **okay**. At least the 3 tasks are now executed in parallel in the background and not sequentially anymore.

However, I would suggest instead of then blocking on all 3, by doing `get()`, you could instead return the futures out of the method. This enables the user to decide how to handle the situation - whether he wants to continue an async chain or work with it in a blocking fashion by doing `get()`. So if applicable, change the method to:

```
// changed return type
public Map<String, CompletableFuture<Object>> retrieve() {
  CompletableFuture<Object> future1 =
                CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> testProxy.findSomething(param1));

  CompletableFuture<Object> future2 =
                CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> testProxy.findSomething(param2));

  CompletableFuture<Object> future3 =
                CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> testProxy.findSomething(param3));


  Map<String, Object> toClient = new HashMap<>();
  toClient.put("result1", future1); // no get() anymore
  toClient.put("result2", future2); // no get() anymore
  toClient.put("result3", future3); // no get() anymore
  
  return toClient;
}
```

Minor note, you can do `return Map.of("result1", future1, "result2", result2, "result3", result3)` to simplify the end a bit.

On that note, I get that this is a heavily edited and simplified example but please check if the `Map` is actually meaningful in your case or whether you could just use a `List` instead:

```
return List.of(future1, future2, future3);
```

That said, in this particular case you could also utilize loops or streams to simplify the method further:

```
public List<CompletableFuture<Object>> retrieve() {
    return Stream.of(param1, param2, param3)
        .map(param -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
            () -> testProxy.findSomething(param)))
        .toList();
}
```

I do have a concern on the missing type safety with your method though. `Object` is not really helpful to an user - but maybe this is not the case in your *real code*.

---

### Does `get()` wait until its done?

> 2. As far as I know, `get()` method blocks until task return result though, why the while loop needs ?

You are correct. `get()` blocks until the task is done (or is cancelled, interrupted or ends abnormally due to an exception). A loop to wait on the result is not needed.

The example code you found is not the best. The loop is bad, it should be removed.

---

### Is the callsite okay?

> 3. If I need to check whether all tasks are done, should I write code like this ?

The actively blocking loop `while(!allFutures.isDone()){}` is not okay and will melt your CPU (100% CPU usage). If you want to wait until all futures are done, just do `allFutures.join()` or `allFutures.get()`. That will be much better.

Yet again, if possible, give the user the possibility to decide and return the futures to him.

Comment: Thank you for your sincere reply! So, considering it in code level, your suggestion("give the user the possibility to decide and return the futures to him.") means retrieve() method and RestController which calls the method should return List<CompletableFuture<Object>> and the user (react app) get the results and extract actual data from it right ?

Comment: Well, I didnt know that your transferring this out of Java. I am not sure how easy you can transfer a Future out to React via REST. This probably needs HTTP/2 and is easier done with a framework like Spring that natively supports reactive REST APIs. My suggesstion was more tailored for the case that the _caller_ of the method is still inside Java. But sure, a fully reactive App has a lot of advantages and is the current trend - I wouldnt try to do that without a framework like Spring though.